# PHP Path to Include Files

Tags: php, .htaccess, include-path

I have a site with an index.php.
The index.php has a number of include files like

```
 <?php include_once('scripts/php/index_mainImageJoin.php');?>
```

I've created a new folder off the root called 'extrapages' and I'm going to have pages in there that have information relating to the site. I've added the include_once files like above and change the path and these hook up fine.

The problem I'm find is paths within the include files fail. eg: if an image or another include file is within the include it fails when run from the 'extrapages' folder. Pathing issue.

Is there a good way to deal with this?
Can I change/set the path to the site root (www) for pages under 'extrapages' to one folder down by chance?

I could move these pages onto the root and they would run fine but I really don't want all the clutter on the root of the site.

Any ideas & thx

Comment: you're including images?! O_o

Comment: If it's uploads, he's asking for LFI injection with that one. >_>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to any path problem is called **absolute path**

- while creating *hyperlinks* for your site (including image sources), always start it from `/` followed by full correct path. And it never fail you.
- same for the filesystem calls: always use absolute path. Your server usually provides you with very handy variable called `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` contains the point where filesystem meet web-server, pointing to your web root directory.

So, when called from anywhere in your site,

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/scripts/php/index_mainImageJoin.php';
```

will point always to the same location

Comment: Downvoted.  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not always available and thus cannot be relied upon (IIS does not provide this var).  If anything, you should be defining a constant (with the output of `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__`) in the front-end files and reusing that throughout the entire script, front-end and back-end files, instead.  You shouldn't be teaching poor and environment-specific programming methods.

Comment: Doesn't mean they shouldn't get into the practice of handling it that way in the first place.  Best to encourage them to learn it the right way and not cut corners.  I've updated my own answer with all this anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on PHP 5.3.0 or newer, you can (instead of what RageZ) suggested, use just `__DIR__` (a newly defined magic constant).

example:

```
include __DIR__ . '/../include.php';
```

Now, this doesn't help when you want to avoid `../` and mapping out your includes.  There's a better way to do it, though - in all front-end files (which should be the ONLY user-accessible PHP files) you define a constant which provides the root path of your script (and not of the current file).

For example:

`index.php`

```
<?php
define('MYSCRIPT_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
// or in php 5.3+ ...
define('MYSCRIPT_ROOT', __DIR__);

// ... do some stuff here

include MYSCRIPT_ROOT . '/includes/myinclude.php';
```

Now let's say we want to include a file in our includes directory.

Let's do it in `includes/myinclude.php`, and include the file `includes/myotherinclude.php`

`includes/myinclude.php`

```
<?php
if(!defined('MYSCRIPT_ROOT')) exit; // prevent direct access - ALWAYS a good idea.

// ... do stuff here or something

include MYSCRIPT_ROOT . '/includes/myotherinclude.php';
```

Keep in mind that the include paths should be directly relative to the **root** directory of the project itself, not to just one of the front-end files.  If you have a front-end file in a subdirectory, you need to back out to the project root itself when defining the constant.

example:

`subdirectory/index.php`

`index.php`

```
<?php
define('MYSCRIPT_ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
// or in php 5.3+ ...
define('MYSCRIPT_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));

// ... do some stuff here

include MYSCRIPT_ROOT . '/includes/myinclude.php';
```

All we do here is add a dirname() call, which takes off a directory in the path.
See: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 0):

you should use [`dirname`](http://fr.php.net/dirname) and the [`__FILE__`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) by using this both constant you should be able to include file relative to the current file instead of the php script called by the web server.

for example

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../include.php';
```

`dirname`: would return the directory part of a path

`__FILE__`: is a magic constant, it's replaced by the path of the current file.

The only problem with doing such thing you lock the structure of your project but most of the times it's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your include path once (somewhere at the beginning or in a config file) using `set_include_path()`, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php). Use an absolute path (not relative; can utilize `dirname(__FILE__)`) and it should work all the time.

Comment: Please, can you tell more about “not relative”? To me it's finer to use relative path with include path defined in a configuration file, than to use a variable in the path specification of an include or require directive.

Comment: Relative paths are okay but they can get rather messy, e.g. when moving files, including them somewhere else, etc.