# issues requiring files in php from multiple locations

Tags: php, require

I have a single PHP file that i require in many different php files.

The PHP file stores DB info and also requires another file called something.php....

Now, say I stored the PHP file (with db info) called `my_db_info.php` in a folder called `config`.

I then have another PHP file that was stored in two folders above the `config` folder, called `all_functions`. Now to require the file with db info I'd write `require('folder1/config/my_db_info.php');` Now this would require my_db_info.php fine but the file required in my_db_info.php (something.php) will not be included which will cause a fatal error.

so when I test the php in the `all_functions` folder, i get a fatal error telling me that the file (something.php) required in the actual db file (my_db_info.php) could not be found.

then, when I alter the `my_db_info.php` file and change the require line to decrease how many folders it goes up or down, example:

```
require('../something.php');
```

To

```
require('../../something.php');
```

It seems to work. But i have to change the folder up/down count to what the main file (in the `all_functions` folder) is. so as if i was requiring `something.php` in that file...

Which means, when i want to require `my_db_info.php` into another file, which is in a completely different location to the file in the `all_functions` folder (5 folders up for example), I will have to make another my_db_info.php for it to all work properly....

Why does this happen, and is there any way I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544784/php-path-to-include-files/7544815#7544815 This is a more reliable method of handling include paths, as it is available on ALL environments and makes your code much more portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it seems the easiest thing for you to do, is the directly include the PHP files rather than giving the relative path (which is how you're including them).

Try using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] (which will give you something like /home/username/htdocs)

If I understand your setup correctly, you have the following 2 directories in a directory (possibly in the root):

```
/
/all_functions
/config
```

The instead of including with multiple `include("../my_db_info.php");` change to `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/my_db_info.php");` and repeat as needed be for other directories.

If you do it this way, it will work for multiple directories away from where the config+all_functions directories are located.

**Edit (in response to comment)**

If `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is unavailable, then you could always manually write the document root, then define it as a constant, then call it in each script.

Eg.

```
define(rootpath, "/home/username/htdocs");
include(rootpath."/config/my_db_info.php");
```

Then you can use `rootpath` as your defined constant in `my_db_info.php` (etc) if needed be, the downside is that you'd have to write this in every script - though fingers crossed that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is available for you.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is unavailable in some environments and can't be relied upon.

Comment: IIRC, at least IIS doesn't provide it (for specifics).  Also, don't use it in a variable, it should NOT be changed; if there's any exploitable code, that variable can be changed to abuse a bad `allow_url_fopen` setting and change all includes into remote includes to some off-site (and likely out-of-country) server, which is basically giving an attacker access to something worse than eval().  Use a constant instead.

Answer (score 1):

**2021 Update**

Now I prefer to use `namespace` with `autoload` instead of traditional importing.

```
<?PHP

namespace Whatever;

class Important {...}
```

```
<?PHP

use App\Whatever;

$important = new Important();
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php